# Apache-Pig, transforming sub groups

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am starting to work with Apache pig, and I am trying to transform a csv file.

If the input looks like this:

```
1,A,10,SS,11
 ,B,11,BB,12
 ,D,12,TT,13
2,A,20,GG,11
 ,C,22,YY,9
 ,E,30,  ,
```

Is it possible to get to the output below?

```
Number, Type1, Value, Type2, Value,
     1,     A,    10,    SS,    11,
     1,     B,    11,    BB,    12,
     1,     D,    12,    TT,    13, 
     2,     A,    20,    GG,    11,
     2,     C,    22,    YY,     9, 
     2,     E,    30,      ,      ,
```

The CSV contains sections that are identified by a number in the first column. The values in the second column are variable in each section.  The number of rows between each section are also variable.

Is Apache-Pig a good tool to solve this sort of problem and how would someone go about processing this type of information?

Comment: Is the 3rd column always going to be increasing? Can we use it as an ordering column?

Comment: No, there is no real pattern to the values except the first row in the first column being the initial grouping field.  The input is a seperate report being converted to a csv.

Answer (score 0):

First process this CSV file using bash shell script, like where there is null ,Add non null value which is above that using sed or awk.and then put the modified file in to HDFS..from there you can start Transformation using Pig.